# How I can draw automatic boxes on specific Candles in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart, candlesticks

I'm trying to program an indicator that show the resistant area

the resistant area should be box ( triangle )

the main idea that the indicator detect the highest red candles with upper tale more that 50% of the candle length

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © TEST

//@version=4
study("--- TEST --- ", overlay=true)

redbar = close < open
greenbar = close > open
low_tale = min(close,open) - low
upper_tale = high - max(open,close)
candle_length = high - low


hiLen = input(title="High Length", type=input.integer, defval=25)
hiHighs = highest(high, hiLen)[1]

loLen = input(title="Low Length", type=input.integer, defval=25)
loLows = lowest(low, loLen)[1]


if redbar and upper_tale > ( 0.5 * candle_length ) and high > hiHighs
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Short", yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = color.red, style = label.style_arrowdown)
```

the demo image as shown now

[image: it shows red arrows, but I wanna it show a box]

this is what I wanna to do

[image]

- I wanna to show the last 4 candles with it's box as shown with the same condition , but i can increase it or decrease it as input

** of course the top of the box is the high of the target candle and the Low of the box is the low of the target candle

Comment: use boxes (https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_box{dot}new) for draw rectangles

Comment: Thanks Andrey D :) , but The main problem that I can't get the candle time

Comment: bar_index or time doesn't work?

Comment: i can't use it :(

Answer (score 0):

Check it - https://www.tradingview.com/script/db9fuGm0-Price-Action-Inside-Bar-Boxes/

This script automatically draws rectangles around bars inside IB pattern, but it can be changed for your task

Comment: Please be sure to review [Stack Overflow's self-promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) before linking to your own content.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.